# How to resolve or flatten object references in elasticsearch mongo river?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, elasticsearch

Is it possible to flatten or resolve references to other collections before indexing to Elasticsearch?

Example I have this schema:

```
var PartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  province : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Province',
    required: true
  },
});
```

Using mongoriver, the province property is being indexed as an ObjectId so in the search results of my application, the province is an object id so it's not useful to the users so I wanted to flatten/resolve the province property so I can access the properties of province like: part.province.name, part.province.createdAt etc...

My initial solution was to use script filters and mappings. Here's what I did:

Defined a mapping on ES

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/parts/part/_mapping' -d '{"properties":{"__v":{"type":"long"},
"title":{"type":"string"},
"province":{
    "type":"nested",
    "properties": {
        "name" : {"type": "string"}
    }
}}}'
```

Created a river:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/pdm/_meta" -d '
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "localhost", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "db": "pdm",
    "collection": "parts"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "parts",
    "type": "part"
  }
}'
```

Created a script:

```
ctx.document.province = {};
ctx.document.province.name = 'Static name to be inserted by script';
```

It works, but currently the name on the script is just static. Obviously I need to fetch it dynamically from mongodb database so I tried using lang-javascript to communicate with MongoDB via a REST api using ajax, unfortunately it didn't work since I think it's not possible to use ajax outside the browser. But even if this works, I not sure if its a nice and efficient solution.

Any ideas on how to solve my problem? Or maybe there are other ways to flatten/resolve object references before indexing to ES using mongoriver? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Note: I also need to auto update the object references in the existing documents that are already indexed when they are modified.

Related problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/e3CelbOkgWk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the easiest way to do this would be using a cron job or sync application of some sort. Why?

1. Elasticsearch is planning to deprecate rivers
2. You would have complete control over what related data is available
3. You would be able to use complex queries to define what gets indexed (a user was updated? update all of their stored data as well)